# using Stanford CoreNLP via web

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

Whenever I need to use Stanford CoreNLP I normally download it and launch it on local machine. In some circumstance I cannot really install it (some restrictions). I wonder if it is possible to use instead:

```
http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/
```

I tried it with pycorenlp wrapper and it did not work:

```
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
nlp_st = StanfordCoreNLP('http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/')
parser_output = nlp_st.annotate('Grass is green.', properties={
          'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,parse,ner',
          'outputFormat': 'json'})
```

Here is what it returned:

```
'\n\n\n\n<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\n<head>\n    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"/>\n\n    <link href="http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp.css" rel="stylesheet" \n          type="text/css" />\n  <title>Stanford CoreNLP</title>\n<style type="text/css">\n<!--\n#Footer {\nposition: relative;\nbottom: 0px;\n}\n-->\n</style>\n\n  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/ner/favicon.ico" />\n  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" \n        href="/ner/favicon.ico" />\n\n</head>\n<body>\n\n<div>\n<h1>Stanford CoreNLP</h1>\n<FORM name="myform" METHOD="POST" ACTION="process" accept-charset="UTF-8">\n  <table>\n    <tr><td>\n      Output format:\n      \n      <select name="outputFormat">\n        <option value="visualise"  >Visualise</option>\n        <option value="pretty"  >Pretty print</option>\n        <option value="xml"  >XML</option>\n        <option value="json"  >JSON</option>\n        <option value="conll"  >CoNLL</option>\n      </select>\n    </td></tr>\n  \n    <tr><td colspan=2>\n      <br>Please enter your text here:<br><br>\n      <textarea valign=top name="input" \n                style="width: 400px; height: 8em" rows=31 cols=7></textarea>\n    </td></tr>\n\n    <tr><td align=left>\n      <input type="submit" name="Process"/>\n        <input type="button" value="Clear"\n               onclick="this.form.elements[\'input\'].value=\'\'"/>\n    </td></tr>\n  </table>\n</FORM>\n</div>\n  <div id="Footer">\r\n    Copyright &copy; 2015, \r\n    <a href="http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml">Stanford University</a>, All Rights Reserved.\r\n  </div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

Should I use it with post and get methods? What is proper format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not hit the Stanford servers programmatically! They're not set up for any real amounts of traffic, and are really only for demos. There are some Docker images you should be able to easily set up on the cloud (e.g., [`motizz88/corenlp`](https://hub.docker.com/r/motiz88/corenlp/)), documented at: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html#docker:

> If running the server under docker, the container’s port 9000 has to be published to the host. Give a command like: docker run -p 9000:9000 --name coreNLP --rm -i -t motiz88/corenlp. If, when going to localhost:9000/, you see the error This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect, then this is what you failed to do!